# JSP/Servlet keeps old session values on back button (browser)

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

So the problem is that i have a InitialPage.jsp page, that does the next thing when load:

```
if (<%=(Boolean) session.getAttribute("error")%>) {
        showPopupWithError();
    }
```

Login.jsp submits a form that calls ValidationServlet.java, that manages the validations for InitialPage.jsp, so, at the beginning of doPost(...) i set `session.setAttribute("error", false)`, and start doing the validations.

If any input is wrong, the servlet will do `session.setAttribute("error", true)`, and redirect to InitialPage.jsp, continuing with the cycle. As the scriptlets load, the .jsp will get the following code:

```
if (true) {
        showPopupWithError();
    }
```

And show the message.
So i continue loading data to inputs, and when everything is ok, i submit the form again.
The servlet validates correctly (so, the attribute "error" keeps set to false, as i had done at the beginning of the doPost(...)).
The problem comes as, when the next page shows (MainPage.jsp), the user should be able to press the back button of the browser and go back to InitialPage.jsp.

When it goes back to InitialPage.jsp, the attribute "error" is set to true, ignoring the last call to the servlet (when it validated correctly, set it to false, and redirected to the next page), and it automatically shows up the error message popup.

So basically the idea is to find a way to conserve session values after pressing the back button of the browser, and i couldn't manage to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: When you press the back button, you're retrieving a page from the browser cache. If anything on the server has changed in the meantime, you should fully (or partially via AJAX) refresh the page rather than just retrieve the cached version (using the back button).

Comment: Ok, so i will probably do it partially via AJAX, thanks!